# Bibtex is inverting two reference from same author in the same year

Tags: bibtex

The following is the relevant lines from the the main `tex` file:

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\bibliography{References/references}
\bibliographystyle{apa}
\end{document}
```

And I have two references inside the `bibtex` file, from the same author and published in the same year:

```
@article{Author2011a,
author = {Author},
title = {{Title}} 
year = {2011}
}

@article{Author2011b,
author = {Author},
title = {{Title}} 
year = {2011}
}
```

The problem is when generating the `*.bbl` file with the `bibtex` command, the place in the document referencing `\citep{Author2011a}` shows `(Author2011b)`, and vice versa for the other reference. Same thing inside the `*.bbl` file.

Anybody knows what can cause this kind of problems?

Comment: The key which you give to your bib entry is arbitrary (as long as unique). BibTeX will then sort the entries by it's internal criteria, according to the style you use, then output the "extradate" information.

Comment: How can I differentiate between them, if not with the key? It doesn't make sense when the reference is shown as `Author2011a` but points to `Author2011b` when clicked on. I tried the solution found here, with adding an invisible command to the title, but it didn't fix it.

Comment: The key identifies each entry, and they must be different. The "a"/"b" part on the label date is generated by the style, usually by some secondary sorting criterium (e.g. the title). But the style does associate each entry with a single label as output: the citation "Author (2011a)" will correspond to the entry "Author (2011a)" in your bibliography, even when the entry key in your bib file is "Author2011b".

Comment: I see. So swapping the keys will fix this. I was confused because I was expecting bibtex to respect the order of referencing as it would do in an IEEE paper.

Comment: No, the message is that the key you put in your bib file is only important to correctly identify it in the citation. It doesn't matter whether the "a" in your bib file matches the "a" in the citation output. As long as you use a key and are consistent in it's use, the output by the style will be consistent too. In other words, there's really nothing to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swapping the two keys fixed that problem. The resulting reference is consistent with what was generated by bibtex.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first there are some missing comas in your bib file and some missing journals too ... In the following MWE I added both ...

Second I changed your used keys in the bib file to `Author2011one` and `Author2011two`.

Now you can see that the printed `(2011a)` and `(2011b)` in the bibliography are created independent from your given keys in the bib file. If you have two same entrys the bibliography needs to change the printed reference to "used year" + "a" or "used year" + "b" depending on the number of same titles ...

The following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Author2011one,
  author  = {Author},
  title   = {{Title}}, 
  journal = {missing},
  year    = {2011},
}
@article{Author2011two,
  author  = {Author},
  title   = {{Title}}, 
  journal = {missing},
  year    = {2011},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3] \citep{Author2011two}
\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{apa}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

gives you:

[image: resulting bibliography]

Comment: As mentioned in the comments I only had to swap the two keys to make them consistent with those generated by bibtex. Your solution looks valid as well.